# Site-to-site VPN disconnecting every minute

Tags: networking, firewall, site-to-site-vpn, sonicwall, zywall

I have a static IPsec tunnel configured between a Sonicwall TZ105 and a ZyWall USG20W.

The problem is that the VPN tunnel goes down every minute and then establishes the tunnel again, when Sonicwall is running the dead peer detection.

This is from the log on the Sonicwall.

[image]

I have been troubleshooting this for two days now and tried everything from firmware upgrade to different encryption etc.

Comment: Please edit your question to include your IPSec config.

Comment: Could this be because of different MTU sizes on the network nodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have heard of needing to turn off Keep-Alives or Dead-peer-detection when working with a sonicwal to third party firewall IPsec connection. Have you tried disabling DPD on both ends?